# grouping overlapping regions based on a clustering factor in R

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by, data.table, iranges

Using the `foverlaps` function from the `data.table` package I get overlapping regions (it shows only 25 lines but it's more than 50 thousand) and I would like to group the overlapping regions for each id taking into account the following criteria:
If they have the same ID and overlapping regions belonging to the same or different group, then:

1. group them all, 2) extend the range (i.e. start = min(overlapping item set) and end=max(overlapping item set)), and 3) place the name of the group of the maximum score.
   For example, given the data set:

```
dt <- data.table::data.table(
ID=c("1015_4_1_1","1015_4_1_1","1015_4_1_1","103335_0_1_2","103335_0_1_2",
"103335_0_1_2","11099_0_1_1","11099_0_1_1","11099_0_1_1","11099_0_1_1","11099_0_1_1", 
"11702_0_1_1","11702_0_1_1","11702_0_1_1","11702_0_1_5","11702_0_1_5","11702_0_1_5",
"140331_0_1_1","140331_0_1_1","140331_0_1_1","14115_0_1_7","14115_0_1_7", 
"14115_0_1_7","14115_0_1_8","14115_0_1_8"),
start=c(193,219,269,149,149,163,51,85,314,331,410,6193,6269,6278,6161,6238,6246,303,304,316,1525,1526,1546,1542,1543),
end=c(307,273,399,222,235,230,158,128,401,428,507,6355,6337,6356,6323,6305,6324,432,396,406,1603,1688,1612,1620,1705),
group=c("R7","R5","R5","R4","R5","R6","R7","R5","R4","R5","R5","R5","R6","R4","R5","R6","R4","R5","R4","R6","R4","R5","R6","R4","R5"),
score=c(394,291,409,296,319,271,318,252,292,329,252,524,326,360,464,340,335,515,506,386,332,501,307,308,443)
)
```

The expected result is:

```
#  1015_4_1_1   193  399    R5   409
#  103335_0_1_2   149  235    R5   319
#  11099_0_1_1    51  158    R7   318
#  11099_0_1_1   314  507    R5   329
#  11702_0_1_1  6193 6356    R5   524
#  11702_0_1_5  6161 6324    R5   464
#  140331_0_1_1   303  432    R5   515
#  14115_0_1_7  1525 1705    R5   501
```

note that for each ID there may be subgroups of regions that do not overlap each other, for example in "11099_0_1_1" rows 7 and 8 are grouped in one subgroup and the rest in another subgroup.

I have no experience with `GenomicRanges` or `IRanges`, and read in another comment that `data.table` is usually faster. So, since I was expecting a lot of overlapping regions, I started with foverlaps from `data.table`, but I don't know how to proceed. I hope you can help me, and thank you very much in advance

Comment: Why is `11702_0_1_5` not in the solution with 464? Is that the same ID then as `11702_0_1_1`? And isn't for the first group the maximum score 394?

Comment: You are right, I edited my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your group is the full `ID`, then you could do:

```
dt <- dt[
  ,IDy := cumsum(fcoalesce(+(start > (shift(cummax(end), type = 'lag') + 1L)), 0L)), by = ID][
    , .(start = min(start), end = max(end),
        group = group[which.max(score)], 
        score = max(score)),
    by = .(ID, IDy)][, IDy := NULL]
```

Output (additional `443` score added as it represents the `14115_0_1_8`):

```
             ID start  end group score
1:   1015_4_1_1   193  399    R5   409
2: 103335_0_1_2   149  235    R5   319
3:  11099_0_1_1    51  158    R7   318
4:  11099_0_1_1   314  507    R5   329
5:  11702_0_1_1  6193 6356    R5   524
6:  11702_0_1_5  6161 6324    R5   464
7: 140331_0_1_1   303  432    R5   515
8:  14115_0_1_7  1525 1688    R5   501
9:  14115_0_1_8  1541 1705    R5   443
```

In case your `ID` group are actually only the numbers before the underscore, then:

```
library(data.table)

dt <- dt[, IDx := sub('_.*', '', ID)][
  , IDy := cumsum(fcoalesce(+(start > (shift(cummax(end), type = 'lag') + 1L)), 0L)), by = IDx][
    , .(ID = ID[which.max(score)],
        start = min(start), end = max(end),
        group = group[which.max(score)], 
        score = max(score)),
    by = .(IDx, IDy) 
    ][, c('IDx', 'IDy') := NULL]
```

Output (lacks `464` from your example):

```
dt

             ID start  end group score
1:   1015_4_1_1   193  399    R5   409
2: 103335_0_1_2   149  235    R5   319
3:  11099_0_1_1    51  158    R7   318
4:  11099_0_1_1   314  507    R5   329
5:  11702_0_1_1  6161 6356    R5   524
6: 140331_0_1_1   303  432    R5   515
7:  14115_0_1_7  1525 1705    R5   501
```

The above assumes that your `start` variable is already ordered from lowest to highest. If this is not the case, just do the `setorder(dt, start)` before executing the above code.